# ObjC: memory usage of delegate vs block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, objective-c-blocks

I'm comparing the memory footprint of delegate vs block in Objective-C, for solving a same problem. For example, there is a worker class who does some work:

```
// delegate
@protocol WorkerDelegate : NSObject
- (void)workHasBeenDone;
@end

// block
typedef void (^WorkerBlock)();

@interface Worker : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<WorkerDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, copy) WorkerBlock block;

- (void)doTheWork;

@end
```

The code is self-explanatory, in order to know when a work has been done, I can use either the delegate or block:

```
@implementation MyObject

- (void)workHasBeenDone
{
    [self doCleanUp];
}

- (void)entryMethod
{
    Worker *worker = [Worker new];
    worker.delegate = self;
    // or:
    worker.block = ^{[self doCleanUp];};
    [worker doTheWork];
}

@end
```

As far as I know, in the above code, `self` as a delegate, is in memory; And the `block` is copied on heap, but I'm not sure, **which has better memory footprint?**

Now I need a number of workers:

```
Worker *workerA = ... // created and set delegate OR block for completion notification
Worker *workerB = ... // created and set delegate OR block for completion notification
Worker *workerC = ... // created and set delegate OR block for completion notification
...

NSDictionary *workers = @{
    "jobA": workerA,
    "jobB": workerB,
    ...
};
```

In this case, block seems to be cleaner, but still, does it have better, same or worse memory footprint?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only way to know is to try it and measure. The specifics depend on the details of implementing each approach to do what you want to do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A block is an ObjC object, so it comes with the same memory usage. You're on the right path thinking about multiple `Worker`s — what happens if you want to do the same cleanup in response to all of them?

With a delegate:

```
workerA.delegate = workerB.delegate = workerC.delegate = self;

//...

- (void)workHasBeenDoneWithWorker:(Worker *)worker {
    //...
}
```

Here you get three weak references to the same object, so no additional storage or ownership requirements. And the same `workHasBeenDoneWithWorker:` method gets called three times. (Notice I changed it a little bit — it's good for a delegate method to know who called it, for exactly this reason: one object can be the delegate for multiple others, and it may want to know whose work it has been delegated.)

Now, with blocks:

```
workerA.block = workerB.block = workerC.block = ^{ [self doCleanUp]; };
```

Because your block is declared `@property (copy)`, this gets you three copies of the block. Even though its source code is the same, the internal and captured state for each will be different. Also, there's no way (as declared) for the block to know whose work it's doing... and if you added a parameter to the block that references the `Worker` it belongs to, you'll have to be careful about reference cycles. The memory usage difference is trivial, but the API architecture difference is more significant.

In general, delegates work well when:

- multiple delegating objects might share the same delegate
- the same delegate method might be called multiple times for the same delegating object

And (completion-handler style) blocks work well when:

- work will be done once, the block will be called once, and then the block will be discarded
- completion tasks are so closely tied to setup tasks that the ability of a block to capture surrounding state is valuable

Comment: Nice, thorough answer (voted). One quibble, though. Your delegate design specifically passes the thing that's delegating to the delegate as part of the protocol design. The delegate pattern doesn't do that "for free". Similarly, you could design a completion handler style block that passes in the object for whom the completion code is being executed. To say "...there's no way (as declared) for the block to know whose work it's doing..." is a fault of the specific implementation, not a limitation of the design pattern.

Comment: Hence the "as declared" qualifier. And the note that if you do change your block signature to pass the delegating object as a parameter, you have to watch out for reference cycles.

Comment: "Even though its source code is the same, the internal and captured state for each will be different." Why would they be different? You only evaluated one block literal once; the state should be the same.

Comment: "Also, there's no way (as declared) for the block to know whose work it's doing" Same thing with delegates, if the delegate method has no parameters. If you add a parameter to the delegate method, you can similarly add a parameter to the block.

Comment: "and if you added a parameter to the block that references the Worker it belongs to, you'll have to be careful about reference cycles." Nope. Blocks capture variables from the outside scope from where they were declared. Parameters are not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

A block callback pattern gives you more control over the memory management relationship than the delegate pattern.

With a delegate pattern, whether the delegate link is a strong or weak reference is determined in the declaration of the class doing the delegating (whether the property is declared `strong` or `weak`). It is usually `weak`. The object being the delegate (the parent object) has no control over what it wants to be.

```
Parent object <----weak---- Delegator
```

With a block callback pattern, the class doing the delegating has a strong reference to the block, but the block, which is provided by the parent object, can have either a strong or weak reference to the parent object, which effectively determines the strong or weak relationship between the delegator and the parent object. It can do this because the block, usually created inside the code of the parent object, can choose to capture `self` (the parent object) either strongly (directly) or weakly (by using a `weakSelf` variable).

So the parent object, using this delegator class, can control whether the link is strong or weak depending on the design requirements of the particular use case.

```
Parent object <----strong/weak---- block <----strong---- Delegator
```